# Specify a different path for Icon and Launch Image

Tags: iphone, xcode

I know it's possible to set a different name for these files. However, is it possible to change their directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file location doesn't matter, as long as they are added into your project and they don't appear in red in your left side bar.

Comment: I moved the files manually in Finder, deleted the red files in XCode, drag&dropped the files from their new location. It worked for the Icons of both my projects). The same worked for the Launch Images of my secondary target (no dependencies, just order of creation). But if I do the same for the images of my primary target, they disappear on the Target preview. Drag&dropping the image from the side bar to the preview placeholder will copy to root... XCode bug ?

Comment: You don't need the preview to work, just add an entry in the info.plist. Well, I tried to drag-n-drop the image from side bar to the preview area I've got this "The file XXX.png already exists in your project.....The file will be copied and added to your project as "optionUI". Do you want to continue?", not a bug, actually.

Comment: Did you click ok ? When I did that it actually copied the file to the root of the project. Or do you mean that I just should move it (I changed the plist already), and let the preview not working ?

Comment: I just tried, and it doesn't work. I cleaned the project and reinstalled the app, and it doesn't have a launch image.

Comment: No, just drag-n-drop an image, e.g. named FOO.png to the side bar. And select the primary target and its Info tab. Add a key named "Launch image" with value "FOO", that's what I tried, and it works here.

Comment: Well, I did the exact same thing. It did work for one target (that I created by copying the original one), but not for the other..

Comment: If you copied the target, you will have two info.plist files, if both of them were modified then I have no idea for this.. :|

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll file a radar. I also can't build and archive my second target (also I can build and make an IPA from it, or build and run on device). My XCode might be screwed up